# The object or library file was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries...?

Tags: c++, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, desktop-application, pjsip

I have Customized Client Softphone Application Which was developed based on Microsip (https://www.microsip.org/source) Open Source Project, this project is using PJSIP(https://www.pjsip.org - PJSIP is a free and open source multimedia communication library) as well, Now I wanted to update my Customized version with latest Microsip Updates, Everything went fine except I got the error message as follows

```
Error C1047 The object or library file '..\third_party\ipp\Win32\speech.lib' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries
```

[image: error list pane from Visual Studio]

I am using Visual Studio 2019 in Windows 10 - Version 1607 for x64-based systems.
Windows SDK Version is 10.0.18362.0.

Is there any solution available to overcome this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild the old objects and libraries using the new compiler?

Comment: Yes While I was rebuilding the complete project I got this error

Comment: Are you rebuilding `..\third_party\ipp\Win32\speech.lib` in that attempt? If your project uses that library, you will first need to rebuild that library and then rebuild your project unless the *source* for that library is also included in your project. (in that case you must ensure it is built and installed before the part of your project that looks for that file.)

Comment: Yes I have totally 28 projects under the solution, and rebuild all of them under the solution